# iPad 2 Web SQL database size limit

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, web-sql

As far as I know, the maximum size of webdb in mobile Safari is 50Mb. I create my database with this code:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', 1.0, 'TestDB', 50*1024*1024);
```

But when I use it, I can not exceed the limit of 25Mb (I measure it approximately by the length of the strings, since there is only stringified JSON). I'm preety sure in my size estimations, since I test it in chrome and check database size through file system.

What could cause this problem?